# Looks OK vs. Looks Good

Tags: bug, status-completed

For reviewing Low Quality Posts, the "Looks Good" option recently changed to "Looks OK" (*cf.*, [Rename "Looks Good" or add a "Looks OK, just Incorrect" in Low Quality Question Review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143015/rename-looks-good-or-add-a-looks-ok-just-incorrect-in-low-quality-question)).

A screenshot of this option can be seen here (thanks to @ChristianHupfer for grabbing this screenshot! `:)`):

[image]

However, if one looks at the reviews for a particular low quality post, one still sees "Looks Good". A screen shot of this is here:

[image]

Similarly, if one looks at the history for reviews of Low Quality Posts, one also sees "Looks Good" rather than "Looks OK":

[image]

Is this a bug? Should it be changed to "Looks OK" to be consistent?

---

**Update**: It seems someone has noticed this on Meta Stack Exchange: [Low quality review records say "Looks Good" instead of "Looks OK"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234986/low-quality-review-records-say-looks-good-instead-of-looks-ok)

Comment: I did not notice that it has changed, but I click very rarely on that button ;-) Are you sure about the change?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Haha, fair enough. And I'm pretty sure about the change. But, at the very least, there is an inconsistency, regardless of whether the change was recent or not.

Comment: Well, since you're sure, it seems to be inconsistent. I will look more carefully next time when this kind of review is in my queue

Comment: Ok, I can confirm now your observation: It is indeed `Looks OK` instead of `Looks Good` (I even made a screen shot). The texts should be changed.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer do you want to edit your screen shot into my question? I was going to grab one when I had a chance, but if you already have one, might as well.

Comment: Well, normally I do not edit posts in that way, but since you ask...

Comment: If it is not a bug, I wonder, why it has been changed from `Good` to `Ok`... mysteries keep our live sweet ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer [Rename “Looks Good” or add a “Looks OK, just Incorrect” in Low Quality Question Review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143015/rename-looks-good-or-add-a-looks-ok-just-incorrect-in-low-quality-question) Also, it seems [someone else has already noticed this on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234986/low-quality-review-records-say-looks-good-instead-of-looks-ok).

Comment: Thanks for providing that links, Adam. I read the threads but I am not sure I understood **Why** it has been changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Related Meta SE answer where I fixed this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235310/262550)